# Is it possible to change the return type of a function called with new

Tags: javascript

I have to write a shim for another abandoned npm library.

This library will be called by others using the `new` keyword. This is what others do:

```
const Noble = require('noble/lib/noble');
var nobleInstance = new Noble(macBindings);
module.exports = nobleInstance;
```

Now I wrote a shim that changes what is being imported via `require('noble/lib/noble');`. To make things nice for myself I want to change what

```
new Noble(macBindings);
```

is returning so whenever I call

```
require('third-pary-library-using-new-noble');
```

I will actually get my own return value.

so for this I need to change what `new Noble(macBindings);` is returning. Reminder. I already managed to shim the `Noble` Function.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to change what is being returned when someone calls the function with the `new` keyword.

In the end, what I want to achieve is that when someone calls

```
var nobleInstance = new Noble(macBindings);
```

I want `nobleInstance` to be `macBindings`.

Comment: then just do `var nobleInstance = macBindings`

Comment: I have no control over that code. I am shimming `Noble` but I cannot change the way `Noble` is called or `nobleInstance` is assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace the instance returned when you call `new Noble(...)` as far as I know, but you can make your `Noble` have the same methods and functions of `macBindings` by iterating through the object, more or less as follows.

```
function Noble(arg) {
    for(var key in arg) {
        this[key] = arg[key];
    }
}
```

You might have to work around the above code a little bit (changing the scope or limiting the properties that get copied over) and it might not fit your case 100%, but it should be a decent starting point.

Broadly speaking what you want to do is to build your own version of `Noble` implementing the same methods and properties as the original version, possibly informing the user that `Noble` is deprecated and should be removed by a certain date, in order to promote refactorings meant to move away from the abandoned library.

Comment: That idea is actually quite brilliant! Thank you!